# Mysql create one-to-one relation

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

```
  CREATE TABLE `persons` (
 `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `name`
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `person_rank` (
 `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `wins` int DEFAULT 0,
 `losts` int DEFAULT 0,
 `rank` int DEFAULT 1000
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How should I create these tables if I want: when one person id added to `persons` then the same person will be add automatically into `person_rank` with `rank=1000`  `wins=0` and `losts=0`?

Comment: run two insert queries, or have a trigger on the persons table for you do it.

Comment: this solution I know, but if I do `FOREIGN KEY` for `id` in `person_rank` I need `UNIQUE KEY`

Comment: so? the person.id id value is already unique. just that in person_rank

Comment: Set id as a primary key in persons_rank as well. It is a one to one, so the primary key is id in both, you should always have a primary key in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create AFTER INSERT trigger on **persons**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `persons_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `persons` FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `person_rank` (`id`, `wins`, `losts`, `rank`) VALUES (new.id, 0, 0, 1000);;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: But how should look like CREATES then? I need UNIQUE KEY for `id` but there is already FOREIGN KEY

Comment: Sets `id` as primary key (create PFK)

Answer (score 0):

I would do as MarcB said and just run two inserts.

Along with what MarcB said, create a foreign key from persons_rank.id to persons.id that cascades on delete and on update.  This will keep them in sync.  If you change the id on persons, it will update persons_rank.  If you delete the row in persons, it will delete the row in persons_rank.

Lastly, you will want id as primary key in persons_rank as well, since it is 1 to 1.

Comment: @JanQ MySQL has a program called MySQL Workbench.  This or PHPMyAdmin may be useful to you in providing a GUI then you can review the command syntax they run.

Comment: Yes i know. I did it but all times i have some bugs. If i edit one field on main table, then in linked table it doesnt change ;/

Comment: @JanQ What field are you editing?  The only shared field I see is id.  This is the reason for a cascading foreign key.  It updates the id if the id changes in the referenced table.

Comment: I have other connected field in booth tables 'status'

Comment: @JanQ Short answer: don't have status in both tables.  It violates 1NF (I believe).  Choose where status fits best and use joins when necessary.